# How can I get an object with all its navigation properties filled, in a database with TPH inheritance mapping using EF Core?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Input
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class InputCounter : Input
{
    public bool Incremental { get; set; }
}

public class InputState : Input
{
    public List<State> PossibleStates { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and need to get a Device (with all its InputCounters and InputStates with its respectives States) by the MacAddress.

I'm querying the database this way

```
return _context.Devices.Select(device =>
            new Device()
            {
                Id = device.Id,
                MacAddress = _myMacAddress,
                Inputs = device.Inputs.Where(input => input is InputCounter).Select(input =>
                    new InputCounter()
                    {
                        Id = input.Id,
                        Active = input.Active,
                        Incremental = (input as InputCounter).Incremental
                    } as Input
                )
                .Union(
                    device.Inputs.Where(input => input is InputState).Select(input =>
                        new InputState()
                        {
                            Id = input.Id,
                            Active = input.Active,
                            PossibleStates = (input as InputState).PossibleStates
                        }
                    )
                ).ToList<Input>()
            }
        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it causes an ArgumentNullException.

What is the right way to do this query?

---

Obs: If I comment the line `PossibleStates = (input as InputState).PossibleStates`, the error doesn't happen, so I think the problem may be related with typecast. However, the line `Incremental = (input as InputCounter).Incremental` don't cause any problem.

---

In Database, I have:

Device table with Id and MacAddress fields;
Input table, with Id, DeviceId, Active, Incremental and Discriminator fields;
State table, with Id, InputStateId and Description fields.

Comment: Do you have nullable columns in your tables ?

Comment: The only not-null field is Active from Input table

Comment: Though you have said that you are trying to implement Table per class hierarchy (TPH) paradigm but your `Input` class is abstract which takes me in the direction of Table per concrete class (TPC) paradigm. Can you please clarify this? In database, I believe you have got Devices, InputCounter, InputState and State tables. Am I correct?

Comment: Are you using code-first or DB-first approach? It will be helpful if you can post the SQL scripts for creating the respective database tables.

Comment: I'm using code-first approach with Table per Hierarchy paradigm. The database, who was autogenerated by `dotnet ef migrations` have an Input table with a Discriminator field and a boolean Incremental field, and a State table with FK to Input table

Comment: I made an edit to explain what I have in database.